# Combine values from two DataTable columns into a new column

Tags: vb.net, dataset

I have a `DataSet` which contains a `DataTable` with columns named `FirstName`, `LastName` and `ComboName`.  I want to assign the the following value to the `ComboName` column in the same row.

```
Dim ComboName As String = LastName & ", " & FirstName
```

I don't want to do this by setting the value of the column manually, because I want the value of the `ComboName` column to automatically update when the first or last name is changed.

I was trying to do it with the `DataTable.TableNewRow` event, but how can I access the values of the specific "new row"?

Comment: I'm confused.  Are you trying to add another row or another column?

Comment: Sorry, in the same row, i want to assign the Combo-value to an existing column. Sorry for beeing inprecise.

Comment: I don't think it's what you really need, but to answer your question about how to get the values of the new row being added, in the `DataTable.TableNewRow` event handler, the event args object contains a `Row` property, so, `e.Row` gives you the object for the new row being added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a calculated column with an [expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.expression?view=netframework-4.7.2)(scroll to syntax):

```
table.Columns.Add("ComboName", GetType(string), "LastName + ', ' + FirstName")
```

Sample:

```
Dim table as New DataTable 
table.Columns.Add("LastName")
table.Columns.Add("FirstName")
table.Columns.Add("ComboName", GetType(string), "LastName + ', ' + FirstName")
table.Rows.Add("Schmelter", "Tim")
```

Now the `ComboName` column of the single row automatically got: `Schmelter, Tim`

Comment: Yes, i know that, but i dont want to add a column whenever i add a datarow. I just want to assign the ComboValue to an existing column in the same row, just in the moment the row is created

Comment: @M.Joekel: you only need to add this column once, the value is calculated automatically when the row is added. Look at my example above.